# Parse.com request per second limit?

Tags: parse-platform

Just trying to get some clarity regarding parse.com request per second limit.
Do they count a 'get' from the data browser as a request? Or is it just
a request that starts from the client side?

I'm working on a project that retrieves a combo of images and text and it's over 30 per second.(around 45).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any request to the parse server is counted and his limitation is described on the website ( with new pricing, default req/s = 30 , so 1800 requests per minute).

Basically you have to retrieve as many elements as possible/needed with less number of request to parse ( balanced with the necessity and performance of course ), up to the limit of 1000 rows for query.

Anyway imagine you already have the list of photo objects ( let's say ,a list of Photo as Parse object ) and each one keep the image file field, any call to the direct image url is not counted for the burst limit

Hope it helps

Comment: I think i got it. So for instance right now when I am querying a class in the data browser...if it has 100 photos, since the request only happens once, it will get the 100 photos.