# Parse.com limitation of 30r/s, how to use the most of it?

Tags: android, api, parse-platform

I am having an application which is storing objects. Thanks to parse it's easy, but in my app I also allow to search for objects.

I use cache in order to make as little requests as possible. But I allow users to refresh the `listView` with objects gotten from server twice a minute. According to my calculations:

`Parse.com` limitation: 30r/s total of 1800r/m
One user: 2r/m

`1800/2=900` users allowed to do 2 requests per minute.

According to above calculations, 900 users who will do 2 refreshes a minute, will use all available requests per second.

Does that mean that my app can use only 900 users in 1 minute? So to have 2700 users I have to pay 600$ a month or let them wait for 2 seconds?

And I am just talking about search, what about creation of objects, logging in etc?
Any idea what is right to do here?

Comment: Seems like their business model is indeed "squeeze em dry". The right thing to do might be to just not use that service.

Comment: Would you mind telling me why ---? I am asking Not to broad/ not to specific question regarding things which are in tags. Anybody can have this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that it seems to be off-topic, but there are plenty of this kind of questions, especially about parse.com and they are not voted down. Just first search in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487608/parse-com-request-per-second-limit  and many more.

Comment: If you're expecting a lot of users and you're not happy with the prices you see for these cloud base services, you may be better off shopping around or even consider to rent blades and hosting your own DB which may end up much cheaper than per-request prices. It does involve a lot of complications though (security, maintenance, administration, disaster recovery, backup and restore, etc.) but can save a lot of money if you're up for it and do your research.

Comment: no clue about the (usage) voting system but perhaps you could get rid of android and api tags.. there is not relevance at all since it is ( as I see it) just a parse.com question

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the reason is: API is there because it is API requests to server and Android is there so users working with android might have better solution for that. Because questions is also regarding design of application (how to get most of the available requests per second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, if you let your users update their view every 30s with a request, then you can only support about 900 concurrent users, and that amount will go down even further based on how many object creation and modification you have do.

Since their model scales linearly and costs 100$/month per 10r/s, which under your math comes out to to about $100 per 300 or less users each month, you have to make a business decision here: is it worth it to spend $100 a month on every 300 concurrent users?

Without any information about your app, we can't really help you there.

Do keep in mind though that you can support 900 *concurrent* users. People who aren't actively using your app don't add to any limit. But how much that helps depends very much on the app itself.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have expected. But I hoped that maybe someone tells me that it can be done somehow differently.